# Redirect on disallowed characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, uri, codeigniter-2

I looked over and over and I couldn't seem to find an answer to what I want, but here goes:

I have a client that is really computer illiterate and I want to ensure that any errors that arise are handled without intervention. The one thing I'm stuck on currently though is the "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." error.

I don't want to simply allow all the characters to circumvent the error. Instead what I'd like to do is simply redirect to a particular URI when this error happens. For example:

www.local.com/project/login/''''  ---> www.local.com/project/login

I looked at doing it with hooks, but I'd like to be able to specify a custom URL when I want to execute the check.

I was thinking about using a call to a library method which will pull in the characters from the configuration, then redirect based on whether the check passes or not, with the current URL and URI redirect as a parameter. Is this the way to do it, or is there an easier way to manage this?

Comment: Your question interested me and I tried to write a workaround, looks like this is one of the weak spots of CodeIgniter as there has to be too much rewriting to accomplish this. I would suggest you to go to the CodeIgniter GitHub page and submit this as an issue because this is surely not the way it should behave as it is a fairly common task.

Comment: The problem is that the function that redirects you to the error page `_filter_uri($str)` is called three times or even more and it's main purpose is to return a clean URL, so if you apply some logic instead of the redirect, you will happen to have your code run 3 times or more. I will look into this more and I hope I will find a solution to this.

Comment: Thanks mate. I already have the class ready to go, its simply a matter of how to best implement it. Its certainly puzzled me for the last day or so now. :S

Comment: Would really want to see it!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wL6kk8UJ

This is what I have so far. I'm sure there's some bugs in it, but I got stuck when I ran into this issue.

Comment: Looks promising, I would stick to hooks if you want to distribute this and would hack this into MY_URI if you want to keep it to yourself! When you get to complete your solution, make sure you answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

I've read all the comments above - but I think you missed the easy way to do this.

Just overload the `_filter_uri()` function, and do whatever you want:

**(Place this file in application/core/MY_URI.php)**

```
// Normally this is not fully uppercase - but for some reason the URI filename is
Class MY_URI extends CI_URI
{


/**
 * Filter segments for malicious characters
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function _filter_uri($str)
{
    if ($str != '' && $this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars') != '' && $this->config->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
    {
        if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", $str))
        {
            // DO SOMETHING HERE LIKE REDIRECT OR CHANGE THE URL
        }
    }

    // Convert programatic characters to entities
    $bad    = array('$',        '(',        ')',        '%28',      '%29');
    $good   = array('&#36;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;');

    return str_replace($bad, $good, $str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The only issue is though, how would I be able to specify my redirect URI from the controller? I want to be able to define a custom URI when I want.

Comment: Your request does not even reach the controller, when you pass bad characters. You could use a route map and modify the code above  to rewrite to the mapped url.

Comment: Just redirect to your_controller/handle_error or something. inside handle_error - do whatever unique error handling you want for that controller.

Comment: Maybe it used to work, however, this technique does not work anymore.  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function redirect()` ... CI version 2.2.0

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Don't you have to load parent constructor here?

Comment: dont use redirect() function using header("Location:http://yourURL.com"); because you have rewirte core files.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution I am using on my project:

File: **application/core/MY_URI.php**

```
class MY_URI extends CI_URI {

    /**
     * Filter URI
     *
     * Filters segments for malicious characters.
     *
     * @param   string  $str
     * @return  void
     */
    public function filter_uri(&$str)
    {
        if ( ! empty($str) && ! empty($this->_permitted_uri_chars) && ! preg_match('/^['.$this->_permitted_uri_chars.']+$/i'.(UTF8_ENABLED ? 'u' : ''), $str))
        {
            return preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z 0-9%.:_\-,()]+~', '', $str);
        }
    }
}
```